# Can't export data tier application in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to export data tier application but it generates error.
I'm using menu Task -> Export data-tier application
Here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well there you have it, out of memory.

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: Well out of memory could mean many thing, like too much data or something wrong with your schema structure or really a liitle memory you have in ur PC.

Comment: Thanks. I used very simple database with only one table and only one row in that table